# editing one layer at a time with react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am encountering several difficulties while working with React Leaflet.

1- I aim to edit a single layer at a time through a selection method, where clicking on a layer and then on edit button would enable editing for that specific layer. Currently, the default behavior of the edit button is to enable editing for all the layers, and I need a solution to either click on the layer first and then the edit button or the other way around.

2- After making changes to a layer, I save it, but the const geo = ref.current?.toGeoJSON() function does not register the edited layer, and instead returns all the layers in their original state.

Here is my current code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { ISectorPolygon } from "../../../pages/[contractId]/secteurs-usagers/secteurs/index.page";
import { FeatureGroup } from "react-leaflet";
import { EditControl } from "react-leaflet-draw";
import L from "leaflet";

export default function EditableGroup({
  polygon,
  handlePolygon,
}: ISectorPolygon) {
  const ref = useRef<L.FeatureGroup>(null);
  //TODO: get the selected layer
  // const [selectedLayer, setSelectedLayer] = React.useState<L.Layer | null>(
  //   null,
  // );
  L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconRetinaUrl:
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0/images/marker-icon.png",
    iconUrl:
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0/images/marker-icon.png",
    shadowUrl:
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0/images/marker-shadow.png",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current?.getLayers().length === 0 && polygon) {
      L.geoJSON(polygon, {
        onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
          if (
            layer instanceof L.Polyline ||
            layer instanceof L.Polygon ||
            layer instanceof L.Marker
          ) {
            if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
              layer?.setStyle({ fillColor: randomColor() });
            }
            if (layer?.feature?.properties.radius && ref.current) {
              new L.Circle(
                layer.feature.geometry.coordinates.slice().reverse(),
                {
                  radius: layer.feature?.properties.radius,
                },
              ).addTo(ref.current);
            } else {
              ref.current?.addLayer(layer);
            }

            layer.on("click", (e) => {
              //TODO: edit selected layer
              // ref.current?.eachLayer((l) => {
              //   if (l instanceof L.Polygon) {
              //     if (l._leaflet_id === e.target._leaflet_id) {
              //       l.editing.enable();
              //       // drawControlRef = e.target._leaflet_id;
              //       setSelectedLayer(e.target._leaflet_id);
              //     } else {
              //       l.editing.disable();
              //     }
              //   }
              // });
            });
          }
        },
      });
    }
  }, [polygon]);

  const randomColor = () => {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return "rgb(" + r + " ," + g + "," + b + ")";
  };
  const handleChange = () => {
    const geo = ref.current?.toGeoJSON();
    if (geo?.type === "FeatureCollection") {
      handlePolygon(geo);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FeatureGroup ref={ref}>
      <EditControl
        position="topright"
        onEdited={handleChange}
        onCreated={handleChange}
        onDeleted={handleChange}
        draw={{
          rectangle: false,
          circle: false,
          polyline: false,
          polygon: true,
          marker: false,
          circlemarker: false,
        }}
      />
    </FeatureGroup>
  );
}
```

```
I tried to add this in oneditstart
ref.current?.eachLayer((l) => {if (l instanceof L.Polygon) {if (l._leaflet_id === e.target._leaflet_id) {l.editing.enable();drawControlRef = e.target._leaflet_id;setSelectedLayer(e.target._leaflet_id);else {l.editing.disable();}}});
```

```
and I tried to change the editOptions

const editOptions = {edit: {featureGroup: selectedLayer ? L.featureGroup([selectedLayer]) : undefined,onStart: handleStartEditing,},};
```

still the same problem

Comment: leaflet-draw is not maintained anymore. I'd suggest to use Leaflet-Geoman instead